# Issue with Array from similar but different table

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I recently used this formula in another spreadsheet and it worked.  I tried to use it on another table with exactly the same columns headings but different information within the table and its not working.

Here is my formula:

```
{=SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(Table1[Val/COArea Crcy])) * (Table1[Employee]=G9) * (((Table1[Cost Element]="96500")+(Table1[Cost Element]="96510"))>0) * (LEFT(Table1[Object],LEN($C$2))=$C$2),Table1[Val/COArea Crcy]))}
```

I know the part that is causing an issue is the `Table1[Employee]=G9`  (because the rest of the formula works without that part).  The employee column is one that I add into the table afterwards and vlookup the information in.  I paste the values and make sure in name manager that the Table includes the column within the range.  However, the formula still will not work.  Yet the exact same formula works on another spreadsheet.

Is there something I can do to get my formula to recognize the Employee column as a part of the table?  I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: Check your data and criteria to see if there are unprintable character such as spaces that would cause it to throw a false negative.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  There was #N/A in the employee column and that was causing it to error.